# Alternative to "Embedded Resource" to make a .resx file publicly accessible

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resources, asp.net-mvc-5, resx

I'm creating a Nuget Package with a sort of basic CMS written in MVC5 that I can re-use across multiple projects. This CMS contains a resx file which, in order to be "Public", has the Build Action property set to "Embedded Resource".

Now, the problem is that when I install the Nuget Package in a project, it physically copies the .resx file in the App_GlobalResources folder (and that's correct, I want it that way so I can edit it) but the same resource is also built in the DLL (because of the "Embedded Resource" setting).

This, of course, creates problems and conflicts. But I have no idea how to fix this. The ideal scenario for me would be to use the resource without embedding it in the dll, but I saw that if I do that the resource can't be access from other projects of the solution (it's not "Public").

Any idea?